# Height transitions go from top down, rather than from bottom up in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm making a bar chart with the following code:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.value) - barWidth / 2;
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.frequency);
    })
    //.attr("height", 0)
    //.transition()
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.frequency);
    });
```

If I add the commented-out lines, then the bar transitions from height 0 to its proper height; however, for some reason instead of "growing" up from the x-axis, the bars start out at their highest values, and "grow" down towards the x-axis. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

The way that this is set up means that you're setting the top of the `rect` to be at whatever y-value relates to `d.frequency`, and then defining the bottom to be on the x-axis itself (by subtracting the calculated y-value from the max height). Given that before the transition you're effectively fixing the y-value, then getting the height to transition, what you're actually doing is just moving the bottom of the `rect`, giving the effect you describe.

> How can I fix this?

The simplest fix is to transition both the y-value and the height, in a manner that keeps the bottom of the `rect` fixed. To do this, before the transition simply set the `y` attr to be `y(0)`, then *after* the `transition()`, set the `y` attr to be the calculated version, i.e. `y(d.frequency)`. Like so:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.value) - barWidth / 2;
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(0);
    })
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition()
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.frequency);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

If you inspect the bar elements, you can see that d3 bars are drawn from a the required `height` to the `y` position. So you should try as shown below.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("y", height)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  });
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "letter": "A",
  "frequency": 0.08167
}, {
  "letter": "B",
  "frequency": 0.01492
}, {
  "letter": "C",
  "frequency": 0.02782
}, {
  "letter": "D",
  "frequency": 0.04253
}, {
  "letter": "E",
  "frequency": 0.12702
}, {
  "letter": "F",
  "frequency": 0.02288
}, {
  "letter": "G",
  "frequency": 0.02015
}, {
  "letter": "H",
  "frequency": 0.06094
}, {
  "letter": "I",
  "frequency": 0.06966
}, {
  "letter": "J",
  "frequency": 0.00153
}, {
  "letter": "K",
  "frequency": 0.00772
}, {
  "letter": "L",
  "frequency": 0.04025
}, {
  "letter": "M",
  "frequency": 0.02406
}, {
  "letter": "N",
  "frequency": 0.06749
}, {
  "letter": "O",
  "frequency": 0.07507
}, {
  "letter": "P",
  "frequency": 0.01929
}, {
  "letter": "Q",
  "frequency": 0.00095
}, {
  "letter": "R",
  "frequency": 0.05987
}, {
  "letter": "S",
  "frequency": 0.06327
}, {
  "letter": "T",
  "frequency": 0.09056
}, {
  "letter": "U",
  "frequency": 0.02758
}, {
  "letter": "V",
  "frequency": 0.00978
}, {
  "letter": "W",
  "frequency": 0.0236
}, {
  "letter": "X",
  "frequency": 0.0015
}, {
  "letter": "Y",
  "frequency": 0.01974
}, {
  "letter": "Z",
  "frequency": 0.00074
}, {
  "letter": "LICENSE",
  "frequency": 0
}];


x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("y", height)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  });


function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A thing that was counter intuitive and caused me to create some upside down graphs is the svg coordinates x,y start 0,0 at the top left corner, rather than the bottom left corner.

Answer (score -1):

I think the attribute("class", bar) is not required and you can use rangeBand() to calculate width and check your Yaxis scale takes value [height,0] and rest of the code looks fine.