# Animate a rectangle height attribute upward D3.JS

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3. transition function to animate a rectangle's height but it animates from top to bottom. Could you help me in animating it bottom up. Here's sample code

```
var h = 500,w = 800;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", h).attr("width", w).append("g");
var yScale = d3 .scaleLinear().domain([0, 37]).range([0, h * 0.9]);

var filtereddata = [12,20,37]
var xScale = d3
.scaleBand()
.domain(d3.range(filtereddata.length))
.rangeRound([0, w])
.paddingInner(0.3);

  svg
    .selectAll("recty")
    .data([12,20,37])
    .join("rect")
    .attr("width", d => xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
    .attr("y", (d, i) => {return h * 0.9 - yScale(d);})
    .style("fill", "orange")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("height", d => yScale(d))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this to start the `y` position at the bottom, and then transition the `y` *up* while you're also increasing the height. Here's a full working example with those two changes.

```js
var h = 500, w = 800;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", h).attr("width", w).append("g");
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 37]).range([0, h * 0.9]);

var filtereddata = [12, 20, 37]
var xScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(filtereddata.length))
  .rangeRound([0, w])
  .paddingInner(0.3);

svg
  .selectAll("recty")
  .data([12, 20, 37])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", d => xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("y", (d, i) => {
    return h * 0.9;
  })
  .style("fill", "orange")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("y", (d, i) => {
    return h * 0.9 - yScale(d);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code snippet in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Glorificus/dr0fjwvc/) I’ve made should do what you’re wanting - let me know if it doesn’t work or if you have any questions though! Answer is adapted from the answers to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126004/height-transitions-go-from-top-down-rather-than-from-bottom-up-in-d3), if you need more info.

From your code, change the transition event to:

```
.attr("y", (d, i) => {return h - yScale(d);});
```

And add the following before the transition:

```
.attr("height", d => yScale(d))
.attr("y", h)
```